# Golang GAE SDK on XP: Do I have to install it? Are there other ways to use the SDK on XP?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

The [introduction](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/devenvironment) says:

> Follow the instructions on the download page to install the SDK on
>   your computer.

But the [download page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads) has no any instructions about how to install and what to do next. Only links.

All I found is this link to [WindowsInstallation](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WindowsInstallation):

> Download and run the latest Windows installer from our downloads page

Must Windows XP users use the installer? Can they just download the Linux version and unzip it? I'd like to have a portable version rather than one that installs EXEs and registry settings, etc.

Also I do not understand what exactly do I have to choose. There are:

1. Google App Engine SDK 1.7.7 (`.msi` file)
2. Google App Engine SDK for Go 1.7.7 (`.zip` file)

I've downloaded the second. Do I need to download and install the first too? Just adding the second to the PATH and develop is exactly what I want. Is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

The Linux version will have executables compiled for Linux, so you can't run those on Windows (unless you run linux under a virtual machine with VirtualBox, VMWare or similar).

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to install something to run Go GAE on XP.

1. I just downloaded `go_appengine_sdk_windows_386-1.7.7.zip` from
   [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go).
2. Unzipped it in `C:\go_appengine-1.7.7`
3. Added the folder in my PATH. The main goal is to have these files
   `dev_appserver.py` and `appcfg.py` in the PATH. It is written
   [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/devenvironment). Not a must, though, only for convenience.
4. Installed Python 2.7.4. Only works with 2.7.4. At first I installed
   the latest 3.3.1 but had to change it to 2.7.4 because Go GAE cannot
   run, throws an error.
5. And that's all. Just created a sample script, ran `C:\>dev_appserver.py myapp` and opened my sample app in localhost:8080.
6. PROFIT.

But:

1. Do not know, though, what benefits the installer offer. I didn't test it.
2. That was just a sample script. Maybe some serious development requires installation.